# Ruby Marshal dump rule

Tags: ruby

I used this ruby code to generate a `.rxdata` file

```rb
class A < Array
  def initialize
    @a = Object.new
    @b = :b
    @c = @a
    @d = @b
    @e = Object.new
  end
end


str = Marshal.dump( A.new )

file = File.open("./users.rxdata", "w")
file.write str
file.close
```

This is the generated bytecode

```
04 08 49 43 3A 06 41 5B 00 [0D] 0A 3A 07 40 61 6F   ..IC:.A[...:.@ao
3A 0B 4F 62 6A 65 63 74 00 3A 07 40 62 3A 06 62     :.Object.:.@b:.b
3A 07 40 63 40 06 3A 07 40 64 3B 09 3A 07 40 65     :.@c@.:.@d;.:.@e
6F 3B 07 00                                         o;..
```

But there is an unexpected `0D` byte in index 9. What is the role of `0D` here?

ruby version:

```
>ruby.exe --version
ruby 2.7.3p183 (2021-04-05 revision 6847ee089d) [x64-mingw32]
```

Comment: @muistooshort (1) `.rxdata` is a binary file generated by me using `Marshal`, the file extension is not important (2) I am learning to parse the structure of Marshal binary file (3) I can explain other bytes, but `0D `I don't know how to explain

Comment: @muistooshort hi, I think I found the problem, can you help me see the answer below, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code in [dump_spec.rb](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/spec/ruby/core/marshal/dump_spec.rb#L21)
`"\004\bi\n"`

so I printed `p "\004\bi\n".unpack("H*").first` The result is `"0408690a"`

I write it into the file

```
File.open("./users2.rxdata", "w") { |file| file.write("\004\bi\n") }
```

and check the bytecode as `04 08 69 0D 0A`

here is `0D` is interpreted as the ASCII control character (0x00-0x1F) "Carriage Return"

so when you execute this code

```
str = Marshal.dump( 5 )
File.open("./users.rxdata", "w") {|file| file.write(str) }
```

will find that your bytecode becomes like this `04 08 69 0D 0A`

how to Ignore ASCII control characters when writing files

Comment: `ruby.exe` suggests that you're on Windows so there might be some CR-LF mangling by default, try opening the file in binary mode (`File.open(..., 'wb')`).

Comment: @muistooshort After using `wb`, `0D` disappeared 